# How to get the content-length of the response from a request with fetch()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I was getting an error when returning `response.json()` when I would do a request with an empty response body, so I'm trying to just return an empty object when there is an empty body. The approach I was going for is to check the `Content-Length` header of the response, however, somehow `response.headers.get('Content-Length')` somehow returns `null`. Here is my code:

```
function fetchJSON(url, options, state = null) {
    return fetch(url, Object.assign({}, options, {
            // TODO: Add options here that should be there for every API call
            // TODO: Add token if there is one
        }))
        .then(response => {
            // Pass the JSON formatted body to the next handler
            if (response.ok === true) {
                if (response.headers.get('Content-Length') === 0) return {};
                return response.json();
            }

            // If the response was not an 2xx code, throw the appropriate error
            if (response.status === 401) throw new AuthorizationError("You are not authorized to perform this action");

            // If it is an error code that we did not expect, throw an regular error and hope that it gets noticed by
            // a developer
            throw new Error("Unexpected response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
}
```

Could you maybe help me to find the `Content-Length` of the response or help me to find another approach?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The server should expose the header using [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) on the server side:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
```

@sideshowbarker [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266678/how-to-get-the-content-length-of-the-response-from-a-request-with-fetch/48266945?noredirect=1#comment83530486_48266945) explains why you can see the header in the network panel of the browser, but receive `null` when you do `response.headers.get("Content-Length")`:

> Just because your browser receives the header and you can see the
> header in devtools doesn’t mean your frontend JavaScript code can see
> it. If the response from a cross-origin request doesn’t have an
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length response — as indicated
> in this answer — then it’s your browser itself that will block your
> code from being able to access the header. For a cross-origin request,
> your browser will only expose a particular response header to your
> frontend JavaScript code if the Access-Control-Expose-Headers value
> contains the name of that particular header.

You can see it working by copy/pasting this to the console:

```
fetch("//stackoverflow.com").then(response => console.log(response.headers.get("content-length")))
```

Note that the return value of [Headers.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get) will be a bytestring, so you will have to cast it to a number to use it in a numerical expression:

```
Number(response.headers.get("content-length")) > 0
```

Comment: The problem is not that the header is not there in the response, in the Developer View of Google Chrome I could see that the Content-Length header is actually 0, however `response.headers.get("Content-Length")` returns `null`

Comment: @jbakker Just because your browser receives the header and you can see the header in devtools doesn’t mean your frontend JavaScript code can see it. If the response from a cross-origin request doesn’t have an Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length response — as indicated in this answer — then it’s your browser itself that will block your code from being able to access the header. For a cross-origin request, your browser will only expose a particular response header to your frontend JavaScript code if the Access-Control-Expose-Headers value contains the name of that particular header.

Comment: Brilliant answer, was scratching my head while implementing a download progress indicator

Comment: Chromium 79, 80 exposes this headers for cross-origin requests without `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by just putting the `response.json()` in a try/catch-block and catching the error that occurs when I try to parse an empty body. This is not the ideal solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this :

```
 if (response.ok === true) {
        if (response.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") === 0) return {};
        return response.json();
 }
```

Or more easily like this :

```
 if (response.ok === true) {
        if (response.length === 0) return {};
        return response.json();
 }
```

Is it ok for you ? :)

Comment: `response.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` returns `undefined`, and `response.length` is also `undefined`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: non-successful responses can still contain json as well

Answer (score -5):

Finally, you can keep your code clean and just write `if (response.ok)`.

Comment: As Ted Elliott said "non-successful responses can still contain json as well"

Comment: Any response can contain json, so responses with ok == false will also return an error