# Find content-length of gzip'ed fetch() response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm doing a large `fetch()` and I want to have a progress bar. When I return uncompressed content from the webserver, the following code works fine.

When I enable gzip on the webserver, the `content-length` reflects the compressed size (which is correct given the HTTP spec) and the stream that I'm reading gives me uncompressed data (which is correct according to the Fetch spec)... however the combination of these two correct behaviours means that my progress bar is useless (it reports "300% complete: loaded 1200KB [of uncompressed data] from a total of 400KB [of compressed data]")

Is there any way to either measure "how much compressed data has been downloaded so far" (to compare against the content-length header) or "how long is the uncompressed data expected to be" (to compare against the uncompressed stream I'm reading)?

```js
    fetch("http://example.com/bigdata.json")
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.body) return;
            const reader = response.body.getReader();
            let download_done = 0;
            let download_size = parseInt(response.headers.get("content-length"));

            return new ReadableStream({
                start(controller) {
                    function push() {
                        reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                            if (done) {
                                controller.close();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (value) {
                                download_done += value.byteLength;
                                report_progress(download_done, download_size);
                            }
                            controller.enqueue(value);
                            push();
                        });
                    }
                    push();
                },
            });
        })
        .then((stream) => {
            return new Response(stream, {
                headers: { "Content-Type": "text/json" },
            }).json();
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            console.groupCollapsed("api_request(bigdata.json)");
            console.log(result);
            console.groupEnd();
        })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the content-length of the response from a request with fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266678/how-to-get-the-content-length-of-the-response-from-a-request-with-fetch)

Comment: Nope - the header itself is working fine, the problem is the header and the body don't match because one is compressed and one isn't

Comment: To calculate the percentage of the downloaded data you need.
`var percentage = (download_done * 100) / download_size;` place it after `download_done += value.byteLength;`

Comment: That doesn't help, because `download_done` and `download_size` are referring to two different things (the first measures how much uncompressed data we've seen, the second measures how much compressed data we expect)